# How to set up Spring to use ehcache with xml? and how to use JCache API to cache only one object without a key?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jcache, ehcache-3

I'm trying to setup a Spring-MVC 4.2 xml-configured project to use JCache using xml-configured ehcache 3.5 implementation.

How can I use `@Cacheable` from Spring or `@CacheResult` from JCache to call a method that doesn't have any parameters and returns one object? The Object is of type `List<String>`. How do I add the generic as a value type in ehcache.xml?

Also in general, what is the proper way of configuring the setup I described above? I started with ehcache.xml but I still have nothing in Spring configuration xml file to connect the project to it.

Here's some of what I have so far in ehcache.xml:

```
    <config
              xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
              xmlns:eh='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
              xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/v3 
              http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.3.xsd
              http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 
              http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.3.xsd">


        <cache-template name="template">
                <expiry><ttl unit="minutes">2</ttl></expiry>
                <heap>1</heap>
                <key-type>java.lang.Integer</key-type>
        </cache-template>
        <cache name="cache1" uses-template="template">
            <value-type>java.util.List</value-type>
        </cache>    
</config>
```

I understand that each `<config>` represents a CacheManager. How can I wire this in Spring's xml?